# Export Dataframe with Sheetname as Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 40 or so excel documents and I want to read the first sheet into a Dataframe and then export the combined sheets to a csv file. The below code works so far,  but I also need to add a column that has the imported sheet name. The sheet name is different for each workbook. I basically want to replace 'WorsksheetName' below with the actual sheet name.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob 
import openpyxl
glob.glob("..\*.xlsx")
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("M:\Completed\*.xlsx"):
        df = pd.read_excel(f,sheetname=1)
        df['Sheet'] = 'WorksheetName'
        all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
all_data.to_csv('Workoad.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the setting `sheetname=None`, pandas imports all sheets of the workbook into a dictionary, where the key is the sheet name and the value is the dataframe of the worksheet itself. Using this, you could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob 
import openpyxl

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("M:\Completed\*.xlsx"):
    sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(f, sheetname=None)
    for name, frame in sheets_dict.items():
        frame['Sheet'] = name
        all_data = all_data.append(frame, ignore_index=True)

all_data.to_csv('Workload.csv')
```

Your current setting seems to only keep the second sheet of the workbook - you could do this by using some kind of filter on `name`.

Comment: The first and second sheet of each workbook have different column headings, but they are consistent across all workbooks (i.e. sheet 1 has the same headings on each workbook and same is true for sheet 2). How would I modify this code so that all sheet 1s are exported to one csv and all sheet 2s are exported to a seperate csv?

Comment: @Dread is there any kind of consistent naming between the workbooks?

Comment: The first sheet always has a department abbreviation followed by "Teaching Load" (e.g. "AN GIO Teaching Load") and second sheet has the same abbreviation followed by "Workload" (e.g. "AN GIO Workload".) Each department has a workbook with these two sheets but with their department abbreviation. Since the abbreviations change for each department's worksheets, I used sheet0 and sheet1.  The structure of the two sheets is different (different columns and data starts on a different row).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pd.ExcelFile` to retrieve the sheet name, as below.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob 
all_data = []
for f in glob.glob("M:\Completed\*.xlsx"):
        xl = pd.ExcelFile(f)
        sheet = xl.sheet_names[0]
        df = xl.parse(sheet)
        df['Sheet'] = sheet
        all_data.append(df)
pd.concat(all_data).to_csv('Workoad.csv')
```

The change to using `pd.concat` instead of `df.append` should speed things up some – this way you only need to build a new dataframe once, instead of forty times, once for each you add. I also changed the index selected. Feel free to change that to `sheet = xl.sheet_names[1]` if you do in fact want the second sheet; python and its packages generally count from zero, even when working with programs that count from 1, like excel.